# How to avoid caching the member info

Tags: php, html, caching, outputcache

I cache a dynamic php page with `ob_start();`. It will cache all the html output from  to ; but part of the html output is not static data, e.g., member info came out of $_SESSION by login. How can I skip caching a part of the html? I mean how to keep running the php code within a cached html?

The only way I can imagine is to start `ob_start();` from middle of the html.

```
<html>
<head>
meta data
</head>
<body>
member info (e.g. Welcome USERNAME)
------ start caching from here to the end
ob_start();
.
.
.
</html>
```

Is it the only way to do so?

Comment: "this way" wouldn't work either. in fact, it just makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to leave the dynamic part empty in your cache but have a wrapper div e.g.

```
<div id='member_info'></div>
```

Now you can fill in the dynamic part using javascript on document load. For example, with jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var member_info_html = ''; //--generated dynamically with php
    $('#member_info').html(member_info_html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a dynamic page, you can't cache it as a static file.
just don't cache it this way.

I doubt you need any cache anyway.